# How to Make javascript Synchronous just for a moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, synchronization, synchronous

I'm display an HTML table using javascript, where for each row i'm runing an ajax request to get some information to write.

Now the problem is, due to javascript Async behavior, the table rows are not written in the order i prescribed.

How can i fix that ?

Here is the function; this function is called repeatedly in a loop from another funciton and is given the parameter id to retrive information.

```
function printOneRow(id)
{

    var User = new Object();
    User.id =id;

    var userJson = JSON.stringify(User);

    $.post('Controller.php',
    {
        action: 'get_commune_details',
        user: userJson
    },
        function(jsonData, textStatus) {

            var row;
            $.each( jsonData, function( index, com){ 
                row += '<tr object="commune" com_id="'+com.id+'">';
                row += '<th field="#" scope="row">'+com.province+'</th>';
                row += '<td field="comidat" >'+com.nom+'</td>';

                if( prev_commune == "")
                    prev_commune= com.province;

                if(com.province != prev_commune)
                {
                    toggle=  toggle? false : true;
                    prev_commune = com.province;
                }

                for(var i =0 ; i< 18; i++)
                {
                    if(toggle)
                        row += '<td class="active" field="" >'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1)+'</td>';
                    else
                        row += '<td field="" >'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1)+'</td>';
                }
                row += '</tr>';
            });

            $('tbody#detailedBody').append(row);

    },
           "json"
          );

}
```

Comment: the row adding code is already sync, you must have a different problem.

Comment: You could have used the [`async: false` option](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) like in jQuery AJAX, but you would really impair UX… Better rethink your process, as in Blag's answer for example.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes, i said it  my post; "this function is called repeatedly in a loop from another funciton and is given the parameter id to retrieve information."

Comment: @ghybs i tried it already, but first it does not solve the problem, and also, it blocks until the whole table is complete

Comment: > "it blocks until the whole table is complete" yes, that is the expected behaviour of sending Synchronous server requests… and the exact reason why you should avoid synchronous requests. If that did not even solve your rows ordering issue, you may have a problem in the order you call `printOneRow`.

Comment: the order is already set by and SQL query i run just before (using ORDER BY ) it cannot fail in my opinion

Comment: Well… maybe you should still check that, just in case. Simply output your id when `printOneRow` is called. What type is your ID? Note that `ORDER BY` may not behave the way you expect on text types. See [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_orderby) with `PostalCode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to add your row in the first call, and only bind the AJAX request to populate it in async on your sub call (using id or [JQuery index](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) ).

The other can be to use tha ajax callBack to lunch your parent (first level) call for the N+1 row